# Mobile app to server protocol

Tags: json, web-services, rest, httprequest, protocols

I have developed an app that use a RESTful API using JSON:
- Server side: PHP
- Mobile side: JavaScript or AS3 - XHTTPRequest (AJAX)

Each time I request data to server from mobile I send "{user, password, info request}", and I have developed my own algorithm to encrypt these data before sending them.

Probably I can use HTTPS to send data in a safer way, and I can use SESSION info to avoid the need of sending user/password in each request.

This is not the problem, the problem is that I have the sense of being reinventig the wheel because this issue must be solved already in a million ways (almost every app needs info exchange with a server through HTTP/HTTPS).

I have found lots of link in stackoverflow talking about using JSON/REST but no one talking about an specific standard protocol.

I have found other places with info:

- http://openmobilealliance.org/
- https://core.telegram.org/mtproto
- wikipedia: Wireless Application Protocol

But I am not sure about the better way for doing it.

Any sugestion?, any tutorial, specification, example or case of use link?

Thanks a lot.

J. Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is one that I've heard of and haven't used yet. https://firebase.google.com/

I am currently building one using JWT and Laravel, and have been pretty happy with it. Using this link as a guide: https://scotch.io/tutorials/role-based-authentication-in-laravel-with-jwt